# probability that two randomly selected integers of an imaginary quadratic field of class number 1 are coprime

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-number-theory

Given an imaginary quadratic field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-D})$, where $D$ is a Heegner number (1, 2, 3, 7, 11, 19, 43, 67, 163), what is the probability that two randomly selected elements of that fields' ring of integers are coprime? [mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RelativelyPrime.html): For Gaussian integers it's $\frac{6}{\pi^{2}K}$, where $K$ is Catalan's constant, and for Eisenstein integers it's $\frac{6\cdot9}{\pi^{2}[\psi_{1}(1/3)-\psi_{1}(2/3)]}$, where $\psi_{1}$ is the trigamma function.

It might be answered by the *Porubský, S. "On the Probability That K Generalized Integers Are Relatively H-Prime." Colloq. Math. 45, 91-99, 1981.* reference on the mathworld page, but that's not media I have access to easily.

Comment: For a reference, try: [Brian D. Sittinger. The probability that random algebraic integers are relatively $r$-prime. *Journal of Number Theory*, 130(1):164-171, 2010](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022314X09001863). This is freely accessible online.

Comment: Although this question is a few months old, I feel it necessary to bring this to your attention. It turns out, papers published in Colloquium Mathematicum are available online for free from the Polish Academy of Sciences (http://journals.impan.gov.pl/cm/) and the Polish Digital Mathematical Library (http://pldml.icm.edu.pl/pldml/browse/journals). The particular paper you are searching for is here (http://tldr.me/2lx4j7). Just click the link next to the Adobe PDF symbol to download.

Comment: @BrianScholl: I had seen that.. I think (at the moment and with a lot of other stuff going on), that at some point soon a list would be more useful.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that in the case of $\mathbb Z$, the answer is $6/\pi^2$, which arises
conceptually as $1/\zeta(2)$.

So won't the same argument for $K$ (of class number one) give the answer
$1/\zeta_K(2)$, where $\zeta_K$ is the Dedekind $\zeta$-function of $K$?

We have the factorization  $\zeta_K(2) = \zeta(2) L(2,\chi) = \dfrac{pi^2}{6}L(2,\chi)$ (where $\chi$ is the quad. char. attached to $K$),
and so the probability should be
$\dfrac{6}{\pi^2} \dfrac{1}{L(2,\chi)}.$

(The formulas you state are special cases of this one.)